# Change values to repeat based when a condition is met in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[image]

I want to create a new column where If my Rom Indicator is 'Y', then pick the Account ID value and swap it for all the IDs as shown below

[image]

I tried using Case statments like this
`CASE WHEN PRIM_IND = 'Y' THEN ACT_ID ELSE ACT_ID END`

Comment: If that was the actual case statement, I think you need to change the second "ACT_ID" to "ACT_ID_NEW".

Answer (score 3):

```
select  t.*
       ,max(case when PRI_IND = 'Y' then ACT_ID end) over(partition by ID) as ACT_ID_NEW
from    t
```

| ID | ACT_ID | PRI_IND | ACT_ID_NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | ACT01 | N | ACT02 |
| 200 | ACT02 | Y | ACT02 |
| 201 | ACT03 | Y | ACT03 |
| 201 | ACT04 | N | ACT03 |
| 201 | ACT05 | N | ACT03 |
| 202 | ACT06 | Y | ACT06 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bhK1r-Ij)

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Lifesaver solution! :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but the output matches so I guess so. It's just a basic self `INNER JOIN` where you only want to join on the records with `pri_ind = 'Y'`

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.act_id,
       a.pri_ind,
       b.act_id AS act_id_new
FROM   tab1 a
       INNER JOIN tab1 b
               ON a.id = b.id
                  AND b.pri_ind = 'Y'
```